# T/F: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n})^{3}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

My math GSI proposed this question to the class today, and even he doesn't know the answer!

(This should be answered separately for absolute and conditional convergence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a general construction which may prove useful. Fix some $k\geqslant2$, some real numbers $(c_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant k}$ and some real number $a\gt0$, and, for every $n\geqslant1$, define
$$
x_{n}=\frac{c_i}{n^a}\quad\text{if}\quad n=i\pmod{k}.
$$
Then:

> If $c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_{k}=0$, the series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges, for every $a\gt0$. 
> If $c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_{k}\ne0$, the series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges if and only if $a\gt1$.

To check this, introduce the $j$th slab $s_j$ as
$$
s_j=\sum\limits_{n=jk+1}^{jk+k}x_n.
$$
Then,
$$
s_j=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{c_i}{(jk)^a}\left(1+\frac{i}{jk}\right)^{-a}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{c_i}{(jk)^a}\left(1+O\left(\frac1{j}\right)\right).
$$
If $c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_{k}=0$ the first terms disappear and one is left with
$$
s_j=O\left(\frac1{j^{1+a}}\right),
$$
hence the series
$$
\sum_js_j
$$
converges. Since $x_n\to0$ and the slabs are composed of a uniformly bounded number of terms, this proves that the series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges. If $c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_{k}\ne0$,
$$
s_j\sim\frac{1}{(jk)^a}\sum_{i=1}^{k}c_i=\Theta\left(\frac1{j^a}\right),
$$
hence the series $\sum\limits_ns_n$ converges if and only if $a\gt1$ and the result follows.

Noting that, for every positive integer $\ell$, 
$$
(x_n)^\ell=\frac{(c_i)^\ell}{n^{a\ell}}\quad\text{if}\quad n=i\pmod{k},
$$
one can apply both parts of the result above to deduce:

> If $c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_{k}=0$ but $(c_1)^\ell+(c_2)^\ell+\cdots+(c_{k})^\ell\ne0$ and if $a\ell\leqslant1$, then the series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges but the series $\sum\limits_n(x_n)^\ell$ diverges.

*Example:* choose $\ell=3$, $0\lt a\leqslant\frac13$, $k=3$, and $(c_1,c_2,c_3)=(3,-1,-2)$. Then $(c_1)^3+(c_2)^3+(c_3)^3=18\ne0$ hence $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges but $\sum\limits_n(x_n)^3$ diverges.

The same example but with $0\lt a\leqslant\frac1{2p+1}$ yields a series such that $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges but $\sum\limits_n(x_n)^{2q+1}$ diverges for every $1\leqslant q\leqslant p$.

Answer (score 7):

Not necessarily. Consider the series
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{3}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{5}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{5}}+\cdots.$$

It is clear that this converges. However, cubing basically gives us three-quarters of the harmonic series.

**Remark:** If the original series converges absolutely, then the sum of the cubes is trivially absolutely convergent. The $|a_n|$ are bounded, say by $b$. then $|a_n^3|\lt |a_n|b^2$, so by Comparison $\sum |a_n^3|$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

let $$a_{n}=\dfrac{\cos{\dfrac{2n\pi}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$$
By Dirichlet test,we easy to find this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos{\dfrac{2n\pi}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$$ is convergent:

But other hand

Use $$\cos^3{x}=\dfrac{1}{4}(\cos{(3x)}+3\cos{x})$$
so
$$a^3_{n}=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{3\cos{\dfrac{2n\pi}{3}}}{n}\right)$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^3_{n}$$ is 
disconvergent: